# Can every finitely generated field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ be embedded into a local field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fields, local-fields

Let $K$ be a finitely generated field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $p$ be a prime number. Can $K$ must be embedded into a p-adic local field (i.e. a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) ?

Comment: For finite-degree extensions, it is a consequence of Chebatorev density. I don't know about arbitrary finitely generated extensions.

Comment: @KentaSuzuki Do you mean when K is a number field? If so, then the completion of K along a valuation over p is the desired local field.

Comment: Ah yes, I agree, my previous comment proves there exists an embedding into $\mathbb Q_p$, but that is stronger than what you ask.

Comment: @KentaSuzuki Ok, thank you for remind me of the Chebatorev density theorem.

Comment: Maybe a strategy is to decompose $K/\mathbb Q$ as $K/L/k/\mathbb Q$, where $k$ is the "algebraic closure" of $\mathbb Q$ in $K$ (the set of all elts of $K$ algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, not alg closed), $L/k$ is purely transcendental, and $K/L$ is finite. Embedding $L$ in some $\mathbb Q_p$ is easy per previous comments, and then maybe it's not too much more work to upgrade this to $K$?

Comment: See this paper by Cassels: https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/5D685D8FAFAC403B5CAE3170656D23B2/S000497270002503Xa.pdf/an-embedding-theorem-for-fields.pdf.  And the addendum https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/an-embedding-theorem-for-fields-addendum/448105F250CB98358EC731D0FEB4A61A.  Cassels wrote about this in his book *Local fields*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As YCor indicates, the question in the title is different from the one in the body. Are we assuming the prime $p$ is fixed or not?
In both cases the answer is "Yes", but if $p$ is not fixed, there are even stronger results. Below $K$ is always a finitely generated field extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Theorem (Cassels):** Given any finite subset $0\neq C\subset K$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such $K$ embeds in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and the image of $C$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$.

See the remark by KConrad (which I was not aware of before, thanks!).

**Theorem (Breuillard-Gelander, following Tits):**
For every infinite subset $C\subset K$ there exists a local field $k$ and an embedding $K$ into $k$ such that the image of $C$ is unbounded.

This is Lemma 2.1 in "A topological Tits alternative". It extends the Tits' lemma cited by YCor in his answer.

I am writing this answer to complete the details in the case where the prime $p$ is fixed.
In fact, instead of looking at the extension problem from $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}\to K$ to $K\to k$ for some finite extension $\mathbb{Q}_p\to k$, let us replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by any countable field $K_0$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by any local field $k_0$.
Then, by induction, we may assume that $K$ is generated over $K_0$ by a single element $t$.
Solving the corresponding extension problem now amounts to choosing a finite field extension $k_0\to k$ and fixing an appropriate element in $k$ as the image of $t$.
If $t$ is transcendental, take $k=k_0$ and pick any element in it which is transcendental over the image of $K_0$ (which exists by cardinality considerations) as the image of $t$.
If $t$ is algebraic, with minimal polynomial $f$, set $k=k_0[x]/(f)$ and send $t$ to the image of $x$ in it.
Thus, indeed, the answer to the problem in the question's body is "Yes".

Answer (score 4):

Lemma 4.1 in: Jacques Tits, Free subgroups in linear groups, J. of Algebra, 20, (1972). [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(72)90058-0)

> Let $k$ be a finitely generated field and let $t\in k^*$ be an element of infinite order. Then, there exists a locally compact field $k’$ endowed with an
> absolute value $\omega$ and a homomorphism $\sigma:k\to k^*$ such that $\omega(\sigma(t))\neq 1$.

This does not answer the question (the one in the body, since it is distinct from the one in the title — the one in the title does not fix $p$).

But the proof is by reduction to the number field case (which you claim to know). Namely, in the present case let $k_0$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbf{Q}$ in $k$. Then the proof basically consists in extending a $p$-adic embedding from $k_0$ to $k$.